# React spring use transition leave/enter collision

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, react-animations

I have two issues.

1. Onload, the bottom links should render only once, but they are rendered twice.
2. When clicking the box links at the bottom, the current links should smoothly fade out and the new ones fade in.
   Instead, the new ones initially fade in stacked with the previous ones.

[image]

what am I doing wrong here?

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-blackwell-72jywy?file=/src/DynamicScreen.tsx)

Relevant animation code:

```
export default function DynamicScreen({}: IProps) {
  const { screenKey } = useParams()
  const [isLeavingScreen, setIsLeavingScreen] = useState(false)
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState<IDynamicScreen>()
  const [screenLinks, setScreenLinks] = useState<IDynamicScreenLink[]>([])
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const isFirstRenderRef = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRenderRef.current) {
      isFirstRenderRef.current = false
      return
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadScreen = async () => {
      console.log("Screen - Loading")
      const { data: _screen } = await api.getScreen(screenKey!)
      setScreen(_screen)
      setScreenLinks(
        [_screen.link1?.[0], _screen.link2?.[0], _screen.link3?.[0]].filter(
          Boolean,
        ),
      )
      console.log("Screen - Loaded")
    }

    loadScreen()
  }, [screenKey])

  const springApiLory = useSpringRef()
  const springLoryStyle = useSpring({
    from: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 },
    to: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
    ref: springApiLory,
  })

  const springApiTitle = useSpringRef()
  const springTitleStyle = useSpring({
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translateY(-25px)" },
    to: !isLeavingScreen
      ? { opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0)" }
      : {
          opacity: 0,
          transform: "translateY(-25px)",
        },

    ref: springApiTitle,
  })

  const springApiScriptHtml = useSpringRef()
  const springScriptHtmlStyle = useSpring({
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(-25px)" },
    to: !isLeavingScreen
      ? { opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0)" }
      : {
          opacity: 0,
          transform: "translateX(-25px)",
        },
    ref: springApiScriptHtml,
  })

  const springApiLinks = useSpringRef()

  const linkTransition = useTransition(isLeavingScreen ? [] : screenLinks, {
    ref: springApiLinks,
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: isLeavingScreen ? { opacity: 0 } : {},
    trail: 100,
  })

  const chain = [
    springApiLory,
    springApiTitle,
    springApiScriptHtml,
    springApiLinks,
  ]

  useChain(
    !isLeavingScreen ? chain : chain.reverse(),
    [...Array(chain.length).keys()].map(calcStaggerDelay),
  )

  const goToLink = (link: string) => {
    setIsLeavingScreen(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setScreenLinks([])
      navigate(`/${link}`)

      setIsLeavingScreen(false)
    }, 1000)
  }

  if (!screen) return null

  return (
    <>
      <div className="dynamic-screen-top">
        <div className="left">
          <animated.div style={springTitleStyle}>
            <h1>{screen.title}</h1>
          </animated.div>
          <animated.div style={springScriptHtmlStyle}>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: screen.scriptHtml,
              }}
            />
          </animated.div>

          {/* TODO screen.actions */}
        </div>
        <animated.div style={springLoryStyle} className="right">
          ‍♀️
        </animated.div>
      </div>
      <div className="dynamic-screen-bottom">
        {linkTransition((style, screenLink) => (
          <animated.div
            style={style}
            className="dynamic-screen-bottom-link-wrap"
          >
            <DynamicScreenLink
              linkKey={screenLink!.key}
              onClick={goToLink}
              text={screenLink!.text}
              imageUrl={screenLink!.imageUrl}
              size={screenLink!.size}
            />
          </animated.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

interface IProps {}

const calcStaggerDelay = (i: number) => i * 0.1 + 0.1
```

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you continue, but what i did first of all is to set `screenLinks` the to an empty array when navigating to new page

```
const goToLink = (link: string) => {
    setScreenLinks([]);
    setIsLeavingScreen(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate(`/${link}`);
      setIsLeavingScreen(false);
    }, 300);
  };
```

and also, if `isLeavingScreen`, then set the width to zero, in order for the next `screenLinks`  to take whole space

```
  const linkTransition = useTransition(isLeavingScreen ? [] : screenLinks, {
    ref: springApiLinks,
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: isLeavingScreen ? { display: "none", width: 0 } : {},
    trail: 100
  });
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-brook-cy8flj?file=/src/DynamicScreen.tsx:1840-2080)

Comment: that might work, but it's a hack, it should work out of the box so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something. Anyway, I ditched react spring in favor of css transitions & animations.